# pip version and patches

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have two libs:

```
A==3.0.0
B==3.0.0
```

A is a requirement of B, so I use in B 2.0.0: A>=2.0.0
*Note that the current version is 3.0.0 and not 2.0.0.*

Now I want to patch the branch of A in version 2.0.0, and I could use 2.0.0-patch01 or something similar. The problem is that 2.0.0-patch01 is NOT >= 2.0.0.

How can I handle that?
A solution is to use 2.0.1 instead of 2.0.0-patch01, but 2.0.1 could already exist because a bugfix was already created during the development. In my case I need to create a temporary version of the branch that exists since some weeks/months without adapting the requirements of dependant libs.

Thanks

Comment: According to `distutils.version.LooseVersion`, `2.0.0-patch01` is `>= 2.0.0`... `>>> LooseVersion("2.0.0-patch01") >= LooseVersion("2.0.0")`: `True`

Comment: Either way, you should use e.g. `pip-tools` to lock down your app's dependencies from loose version specifiers such as `A>=2.0.0,A<2.0.1` to specific versions.

Comment: Oh, I will double check the error. Thanks very much.